# How to convert a timestamp(yyyy-mm-dd-h-m-s to a date (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: sql, date, datetime, netezza

I have a timestamp field that I need to drop the hrs,min,sec from so I can count by dates.

I've tried `to_date`, `date_trunc`, `to_char`

```
name.BIRTH_DT_TM = to_date(name.BIRTH_DT_TM,'DD mm YYYY HH24":"MI":"SS')
```

I would like `name.BIRTH_DT_TM` to show as `YYYY-DD-MM` without the Hours Minutes and Seconds

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_date_time_funcs.html):

```
select date_trunc('day', name.birth_dt_tm)
```

Comment: @RyonPrice . . . Netezza probably needs a string there, as does Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use

cast(name.birth_dt_tm as date)